# how to deploy a SharePoint solutions without installing SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell

Is it possible to develop a SharePoint solutions in local machine,Without installing SharePoint Server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per your question you have used to difference words. Let me explain both.

**how to deploy a SharePoint solutions without installing SharePoint? :** No you cannot deploy solutions if you don't have SharePoint in your development system.

**Is it possible to develop a SharePoint solutions in local machine, :** Yes it is possible to develop, you need required dll's to referenced. But it is a big pain developing code without SharePoint. As after every change you will have to copy the `wsp` manually to the server where you have SharePoint, and then deploy using `powershell`.

Comment: Just curious, you can still install the SP solution via GUI right? As long as the user is farm admin, he/she should be able to install the wsp?

Comment: That I have already mentioned, my saying as it is headache deploying after every small change, just like we keep on deploy on our development server after every change to test any issues

Answer (score 2):

No, because if there is no SharePoint Server in place, your PowerShell script will fail. When you don't have SharePoint installed, you have to run Add-PSSnapin referenceing SharePoint, which you don't have.

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

no, it's actually not possible.

There are some tries on the internet with which you are copying Keysets from Registry from the Server with the installed Sharepoint to your PC. But these approaches doen't work at all. (Self tried them...)

So you have to install your Visual Studio/IDE on the same machine as SharePoint because the IDE checks even in the Solution Creation Step if there is a available SharePoint Installation on your machine.

Sorry, bro.

EDIT: But it is possible to develop SharePoint 2013 Apps on a machine which has no SharePoint installed. But in SharePoint 2013 Apps you can only use Javascript and ASP.NET as frontend. (There is no backend in SharePoint 2013 Apps...)